# Error 'TypeError: jsPDF is undefined' al usar jsPDF-AutoTable

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Al parecer el error se origina en el archivo: `\lib\jspdf-autotable\dist\jspdf.plugin.autotable.js`.

Estoy usando nodeJS y angularJS 1.3 
Solo realice el `bower install..`  y en mi archivo config agregue esto:

> 'public/lib/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js',
>   'public/lib/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js'

y al cargar la pagina me arroja el error antes mencionado.
*O en su defecto agradecería la recomendación de otra herramienta para la creacion de PDF*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El orden de los ficheros afecta el resultado: no puedes cargar el plugin para JSPDF antes de cargar JSPDF, porque habrá dependencias que harán que ocurran estos fallos. Y no sólo para JSPDF, en general todas las extensiones/plugins/módulos/etc. de una biblioteca o framework deben cargarse después de cargar dicha biblioteca o framework para que funcionen correctamente.

Pon esto en el config y prueba de nuevo:

> 'public/lib/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js', 'public/lib/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js'